# Instead of getting random post to display , i want to show posts of the same tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using WordPress version 5.3.2, PHP 7.4.  let me explain in details to you. The original code i posted above is in my function.php. it makes use of this shortcode " [random_post] "  to display random post title anywhere i insert the shortcode in my theme.

In my own case i inserted the shortcode after the second paragraph of each post in my WordPress with another function and it's working.

But my question is this, instead of showing random post, i want it to be displaying article that are related to the original post by tag. And if there is none, it should be blank.

```
function sc_random_post($atts, $content = null){
    $html = '';
    $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
    foreach($posts as $single_post){
        $html .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink($single_post) . '" title="' . get_the_title($single_post) . '">' . get_the_title($single_post) . '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('random_post', 'sc_random_post');
```

Comment: I think you should rewrite the question so that we can actually understand what you mean and help you.

Comment: @ValentinSoveaux i think it's a bit comprehensive now, right?

Comment: Are you referring to Web Scraping?

Comment: @CaseyHarrils NO